# Gnome 3 always hangs after logon

Tags: 12.04, gnome, lightdm, xserver

The problem I'm having is that after logging into `GNOME Shell 3.4.1` on `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS`.

After a short period of time (approx 0-2 minutes) gnome shell becomes unresponsive.

Hovering on the corner / clicking on activities button doesn't do anything,
Windows get stuck (the application is responding but the gnome is not)
Also the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't do anything.

The only way I know how to resolve this issue is to go to linux shell by pressing
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>any from F1 to F6</kbd>, login and restart the lightdm service.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

So the question is How to solve the Gnome 3 hang after logon problem?

```
hertz@hertzbox:~$ uname -a
Linux hertzbox 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

hertz@hertzbox:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

hertz@hertzbox:~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.4.1
```

P.S. It's the same with or without extensions loaded

---

## EDIT 1

***.xsession-errors***

```
(gnome-settings-daemon:1365): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion `string != NULL' failed

(gnome-settings-daemon:1365): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(gnome-settings-daemon:1365): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion `value != NULL' failed

(gnome-settings-daemon:1365): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'picture-uri' in 'org.gnome.desktop.background' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

** (nautilus:1585): WARNING **: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA

** (nautilus:1585): WARNING **: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout
** Message: Stopping registered applet secret agent because GNOME Shell is running
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

(gnome-shell:1546): folks-WARNING **: Failed to find primary PersonaStore with type ID 'eds' and ID 'system'.
Individuals will not be linked properly and creating new links between Personas will not work.
The configured primary PersonaStore's backend may not be installed. If you are unsure, check with your distribution.
** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1000004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


** (zeitgeist-datahub:1867): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:133: Desktop file for "file:///home/hertz/projects/chrome-steamgifts-notifier/js/options/options.js" was not found, exec: sublime_text, mime_type: application/javascript

** (zeitgeist-datahub:1867): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:133: Desktop file for "file:///home/hertz/Sublime%20Text%202/Icon/256x256/sublime_text.png" was not found, exec: gnome-desktop-item-edit, mime_type: image/png

** (zeitgeist-datahub:1867): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:133: Desktop file for "file:///home/hertz/Sublime%20Text%202/sublime_text" was not found, exec: gnome-desktop-item-edit, mime_type: application/octet-stream

** (zeitgeist-datahub:1867): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:133: Desktop file for "file:///home/hertz/Desktop/christmasTree/tree.py" was not found, exec: python, mime_type: text/x-python

** (zeitgeist-datahub:1867): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:133: Desktop file for "file:///home/hertz/projects/chrome-steamgifts-notifier/js/test.js" was not found, exec: sublime_text, mime_type: application/javascript

** (nautilus:1585): WARNING **: Error calling current_status: Method "current_status" with signature "" on interface "com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Status" doesn't exist


** (nautilus:1585): CRITICAL **: syncdaemon_status_info_get_online: assertion `SYNCDAEMON_IS_STATUS_INFO (sinfo)' failed
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1a00003 (Unlock Log) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

(gnome-settings-daemon:1365): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gkr-Message: secret service disappeared while waiting for prompt

(nm-applet:1582): Gdk-WARNING **: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

[1586:1617:0105/225607:ERROR:native_backend_gnome_x.cc(664)] Keyring find failed: Error communicating with gnome-keyring-daemon

(nautilus:1585): Gdk-WARNING **: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.


(gnome-shell-calendar-server:1675): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-shell-calendar-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

[1586:1586:0105/225607:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_x11.cc(62)] X IO Error detected

(gdu-notification-daemon:1856): Gdk-WARNING **: gdu-notification-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.


(evolution-alarm-notify:1895): Gdk-WARNING **: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.


(update-notifier:1946): Gdk-WARNING **: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.


(deja-dup-monitor:1960): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner :1.34 of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.GduVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts

(deja-dup-monitor:1960): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner :1.35 of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts

(deja-dup-monitor:1960): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner :1.36 of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts

** (zeitgeist-datahub:1867): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't find anything interesting there could you please provide more information for what and were i should search or

Comment: (1) Can you post the .xsession-errors into your question? (2) Did you switch to gnome 3 recently or have been using it for awhile?

Comment: (1) I've added xsession-errors file (2) Its a fresh install of ubuntu and gnome 3 from apt repository

Comment: Actually the xsession-errors is showing big problem. Nothing is starting up correctly. Since this is a new install, I will put a work around in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues with Ubuntu 12.04 and Gnome 3.4. I managed to minimize the frequency of the freezes by doing the following:

- Disable proprietary video drivers
- Add **ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3** to sources and update
- Also you can try to wait for 30 sec. before logging in. It might sound silly, but I think not all components are ready when the login screen is presented to the user. (you can blame Canonical for trying to cheat on the start-up times :) )

The only thing that solved this problem for good, in my case at least, was to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 and Gnome 3.6.

Comment: Thanks adding gnome3 repo and updating did somehow solve the issue. Gnome is still the same version but now works :/ And I'm going to update to Gnome 3.6 when i have time.

Answer (score 1):

## Workaround

As this is a flash install, we can create a new user.

1. Login from text terminal
2. Add a new user

   ```
   sudo adduser <username>
   ```
3. Add new user to `sudo` group, or `admin`

   ```
   sudo adduser <username> sudo
   ```
4. Switch back to X and try login with new user

## Things To Try

- Update

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

Comment: It didn't help. And there are no updates available and i don't wanna upgrade my distribution.

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is not release version upgrade. It only update packages within your current release. If you are using 12.04, it will stay 12.04. The command to do release upgrade is `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Can you check you have dbus installed and running? What you describe fit if dbus is missing.

Comment: (1) 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(2) dbus start/running, process 768.

But the problem persists :(

Comment: you have to restart lightdm after dbus start.

Comment: @George Restart your Linux box, wait till LightDM login screen come up, switch to text terminal (ctrl-alt-f1), login, do following command `pstree > pstree.txt`. Then post that file into the question.

Comment: 1 additional question, do you have same problem with unity?